# How to reset user´s password by Devise authentication token directly from edit_page in Active Admin?

Tags: activeadmin

I would like the admin_user to be able to reset user´s password from Active Admin edit_page, but am currently stuck.

My idea was to make an action_item button and launch @user.send_reset_password_instructions method from devise authentication gem for a users object which works. But, action_item cannot get any notice: message and that´s where I´m stuck.

Can you please help me implement the action_item button which could launch the @user.send_reset_password_instructions, redirect to the same user_edit_page and flash notice message sending successful without rendering any other view??

```
action_item :reset_password,only: :edit do
  link_to "Reset password",edit_timein_employee_path
end

controller do
   def reset_password
    super do |success,failure|
    employee.send_reset_password_instructions
  end
 end
end
```

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way: make sure to paste this in the `app/admin/admin_user.rb` file. I would not add controller methods directly but would use the `member_action` dsl directive to add logic. Good luck!

```
action_item :reset_password, :only => :edit do
 link_to 'Reset password',  do_password_reset_admin_admin_user_path(resource), :method => :post
end

member_action :do_password_reset, :method => :post do
  flash.notice = "A mail containing password reset instructions has been sent to: #{resource.email}"
  resource.send_reset_password_instructions
  redirect_to edit_admin_admin_user_path(resource) and return
end
```

Comment: Excellent!!!...with little adaptation to my example,your answer works in an instance!And finally helps me to fully understand the connection between member action and action_item.I spent many hours trying to do with member_action while the answer was all the time there, right in front of my eyes!!..I just coudn´t see the significance.The link from action_item to member_action was the trouble,and is so easy now,just need to check well the Routes! Thank you very much,really great help and school for me!!