# code reusability issue in active admin rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

How to avoid common code used in active admin action item and controller action.
I have seen people used to write the same code in the controller and active admin action item.
Is there any way to avoid it?

Example is like i want to cancel a user and it requires 3-4 steps to do it.
So i have writtent this code in users controller.

Now i have resource user in active admin and i want to delete the user from active admin. I have created an action item and again written the same code of deleting the user in the member action.

Is there any way to avoid above.

Comment: Could you provide a specific example?

Comment: @SjorsBranderhorst i have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share code between different controllers, you should look to the rails concerns https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.2/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is in the `User` register block (probably at `app/admin/users.rb`) this might help you. The action_item only contains a link (actually a form that posts) to the actual member_action. This is just example code:

```
action_item :cancel_user, :only => :edit do
 link_to 'Cancel user',  do_cancel_user_admin_user_path(resource),   method => :post
end

member_action :do_cancel_user, :method => :post do
  flash.notice = "User will be canceled"
  resource.cancel # I guess this would the 4 lines of code that you are repeating
  redirect_to edit_admin_user_path(resource) and return
end
```

Let me know if this did/did not confuse you. Good luck!

P.S. A few weeks ago someone asked something similar, this might also be of help: [How to reset user´s password by Devise authentication token directly from edit_page in Active Admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54470272/how-to-reset-user%c2%b4s-password-by-devise-authentication-token-directly-from-edit-p/54481543#54481543)